# Redux Observable epic, set timeout interval between actions

Tags: react-redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have this epic:

```
export const updateIsNotVeganInDbFulfilledEpic: Epic < * , * , * > = (
        action$: ActionsObservable < * > ,
        store: Store < * , * >
    ): Observable < any > =>
    action$.ofType('UPDATE_IS_NOT_VEGAN_IN_DB_FULFILLED').mergeMap(action => {
        return Observable.of(
            updateToastComponentIsOpen(true),
            updateToastComponentMessage(action.payload.response.errors[0])
        )
    })
```

How can I dispatch another action (`updateToastComponentIsOpen(false)`) 2 seconds after `updateToastComponentIsOpen(true)`?

I tried this:

```
  action$.ofType('UPDATE_IS_NOT_VEGAN_IN_DB_FULFILLED').mergeMap(action => {
    return Observable.of(
      updateToastComponentIsOpen(true),
      updateToastComponentMessage(action.payload.response.errors[0])
    ).timeout(2000)
    .flatMap(function(result) {
      return Observable.of(updateToastComponentIsOpen(false))
    })
  })
```

But it stopped the first two actions from being dispatched.

Answer (score 2):

The `flatMap` is swallowing your first two actions. Additionally, `timeout` is used to send an *error notification* if something doesn't arrive within the specified time frame.

Instead, you want to introduce a `delay`:

```js
export const updateIsNotVeganInDbFulfilledEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>,
  store: Store<*, *>
): Observable<any> => action$
  .ofType('UPDATE_IS_NOT_VEGAN_IN_DB_FULFILLED')
  .mergeMap(action =>
    Observable.concat(
      Observable.of(
        updateToastComponentIsOpen(true),
        updateToastComponentMessage(action.payload.response.errors[0]),
      ),
      Observable.of(updateToastComponentIsOpen(false)).pipe(
        delay(2000)
      ),
    )
  )
```

Comment: The above example is mostly correct, except for the last action that you wish to delay from dispatching must be piped first before applying the delay. So it would look more like this:

`Observable.of(updateToastComponentIsOpen(false)).pipe(delay(2000))`

Comment: Thanks, @scinatl! I updated the example in the answer.